# В React div должен содержать один дочерний элемент?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, документация

```
class Chosen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
<select className="Chosen-select" ref={el => this.el = el}>{this.props.children}
        </select>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

В документации по React в статье про  [Взаимодействие с сторонними библиотеками](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html) под данным кодом написано, что

> React всегда ожидает только один дочерний элемент для . Так мы
> гарантируем, что обновления React не будут конфликтовать с
> дополнительным узлом, добавляемым Chosen. Если вы собираетесь изменять
> DOM вне React, важно убедиться, что React не взаимодействует с
> DOM-узлами.

Является ли утверждение в документации ошибкой или я не правильно интерпретирую его смысл?
Если я правильно понимаю необходимо наличие одного **родительского элемента**, который в свою очередь может вмещать неограниченное количество **дочерних**

Answer (score 1):

Компонент должен возвращать один один элемент. Чтобы не создавать лишние DOM-элементы, Вы можете оборачивать нужные дочерние элементы в [React.Fragment](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html)

```
const SomeComponent = () =>
    <React.Fragment>
       <div>div1</div>
       <div>div2</div>
       ...
    <React.Fragment/>
```

или

```
const SomeComponent = () =>
    <>
       <div>div1</div>
       <div>div2</div>
       ...
    </>
```

что является сокращением React.Fragment.

Еще одним вариантом является возврат массива элементов:

```
const SomeComponent = () => {
   //какая-то логика
   
   return ([
      <div>div1</div>,
      <div>div2</div>,
      <div>div3</div>,
      ...
   ])
}
```